# Convert a user inputted time to UNIX Time? [Android]

Tags: android, date, time

How would I convert a user given time, using the time picker would be fine, into UNIX time assuming the user inputted a time in the same time zone that they are currently in?

Comment: What do you mean by "UNIX Time"?

Comment: What is the format that the time is stored in? Date object? String? Calendar object? Long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) to convert values provided by the user to valid Unix timestamps

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(2011, 9, 3);
cal.getTimeInMillis();
```